# Simple expected value manipulations (in estimation problem)

Tags: probability, estimation, parameter-estimation

> Let $\hat{\theta}_{1}$ $\hat{\theta}_{2}$ $\hat{\theta}_{3}$ be three
>   estimators of the parameter $\theta$. E($\hat{\theta}_{1}$) =
>   E($\hat{\theta}_{2}$) = $\theta$, E($\hat{\theta}_{3}$) $\ne$ $\theta$,
>   V($\hat{\theta}_{1}$) = 12 and V($\hat{\theta}_{2}$) = 10 and E($\hat{\theta}_{3} - \theta) ^ 2 = 6$. Which of
>   these estimators you prefer ? Why?

$$ E(\hat{\theta_{3}} - \theta)^2 = 6 $$
I get
$$ E(\hat{\theta_{3}}^2 - 2\theta\hat{\theta_{3}} + \theta^2) = 6 $$
$$ E(\hat{\theta_{3}}^2) - E(2\theta\hat{\theta_{3}}) + E(\theta^2) = 6 $$

At this point, I don't know what to do.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I would like to find the value of $E(\hat{\theta})$ if possible

Comment: There's some error in the middle term in the last equation.

Comment: @leonbloy corrected

Comment: Would you say $\theta$ is a random variable or a constant?

Comment: @leonbloy $\theta$ is a parameter and $\hat{\theta}$ is an estimator of this parameter

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @leonbloy constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are in the context of classical parametric estimation, the parameter $\theta$ is a constant, while the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is a random variable (it depends on the sample). Keeping that in mind, and knowing that if $k$ is constant $E(k)=k$ and $E(kX)=kE(X)$ the manipulation is simple:
$$E(\hat{\theta}^2) - E(2\theta\hat{\theta}) + E(\theta^2)=E(\hat{\theta}^2) - 2 \theta E(\hat{\theta}) + \theta^2$$
This can be further simplified if you know that the estimator is unbiased. If you don't know that (as your comment seems to imply), then there's not much else to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am still stuck.. I edited my question to give more information.

Comment: > "In fact, I am trying to find the best estimator between 3 options"
I'm getting tired. The best according to what? If regarding squared error, then the original equation gives you already the squared error, it's 6.

Comment: I edited the question to give you exactly the data of the exercise I am trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry my man, I was not looking at the right definition. I only had knowledge of the theorem $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = V(\hat{\theta}) + [ Error(\hat{\theta}) ] ^2 $ and did not know that $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = E [ (\hat{\theta} - \theta) ^ 2 ]$ was directly the definition of the mean squared error.. Thank you for your time.